# algolia Instantsearchjs how to display and search using <Searchbox> globally on an ecommerce website

Tags: javascript, laravel-5, algolia, instantsearch.js

Im using instantsearch.js , my website is an ecommerce application in laravel and algolia is working perfect on hits page.

[image]

My main question is how can I implement *SearchBox* in other webpages (home, static, etc) allowing people to write on header searchbox and when they press enter -> be forwarded to my search results page (eg: www.example.com/search/query?q=apple)

Taking into consideration Im using instantsearch.js completely, my controller and routes in laravel are not passing any variable into that view.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using InstantSearch for Vue or the "pure js" version? Could you try using the searchOnEnterKeyPressOnly parameter and see if it's what you're looking for? https://community.algolia.com/instantsearch.js/v2/widgets/searchBox.html#struct-SearchBoxWidgetOptions-searchOnEnterKeyPressOnly

Comment: thanks @JulienBourdeau . Im using pure js. I will try searchOnEnterKeyPressOnly option

Comment: @JulienBourdeau my problem is: How to invoke searchbox in every page on the website. My idea is to place searchbox in header, when people type inside searchbox and press enter, the searchbox send them to the result page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally for static pages or all other pages I used something like:

```
<input id="myInput" value="Some text..">
<button id="myBtn" onclick="javascript:alert('Hello World!')">Button</button>

<script>
var input = document.getElementById("myInput");
input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        document.getElementById("myBtn").click();
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

as I understand, you want to make a global variables for your views..

Well, you can use view composers for that, add this on your 
`AppServiceProvider`

```
 public function boot()
    {
        View::share('key', 'value');
    }
```

For more information, you can look at [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/master/views#view-composers)